# error while converting Django template engine to jinja2, unable to use 'with'

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have converted a small Django project to use jinja2 as a backebd engine. Now in one of the templates I am writing the following code:

```
{% include 'base/rating.html' with rating=location.get_average_rating() %}
```

The code above works fine with the Django template but when I switch the template engine to Jijna2 I am getting the following error.

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/location/
>   Django Version: 1.10.5
>   Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>   Exception Value:
>   ("expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'",)
>   ]

and the browser shows the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSj2o.png)

Really want to know how I need to change such code for it to work in jinja2. tried multiple things from jinja documentation about #with-statement but nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [with statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#with-statement).

```
{% with rating=location.get_average_rating() %}
    {% include 'base/rating.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```